# PencilKit '.monoline' as a PKInkingTool.InkType suddenly doesn't work anymore

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, pencilkit

I am writing a program using `PencilKit`. Yesterday, everything worked fine with this line:

```
@State var pencilStyle: PKInkingTool.InkType = .monoline
```

But today, i am getting this Error:

> Type 'PKInkingTool.InkType' has no member 'monoline'"

When I started Xcode Today, it downloaded a new Simulator for iOS 16.2.
How can I fix this issue? I can't use my Project without fixing this...

Comment: Same issue, a month ago it was fine, now it's not present. And also you cannot find any mentions of monoline and fountainpen on the internet, neither in 16.1 release notes where they were present, nor in docs. It seems that Apple decided to keep these features to themselves.

Comment: That is the only documentation that I can find about .monline: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pencilkit/pkinkingtool/inktype/monoline?language=o_9

Comment: I also found your fountainpen in the Documentation (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pencilkit/pkinkingtool/inktype/fountainpen?changes=__7_8) So I actually dont know why they made it like that and how I possibly can work with the .monoline and .fountainpen again... - Do you have any Ideas? I mean it is technically still in the documentation under InkTypes, but its somehow not declared in their enum from the Inktypes...